# How do I approach this calculus problem?

Tags: calculus

The general equation is $a^2 + b^2 = c\cdot a^2$  where c is a positive constant and a > 0.

The question is: ***Prove that the above equation has two horizontal tangents and state the equations of both tangents.***

I know that since it is a circle it would have two horizontal tangents, but how do I prove that and how do I find the equations of the tangents?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

The statement of the question is not true.

Investigate what happens if $c =1$, $c<1$ and $c>1$.

For the setting where $c>1$, we have $$b^2=(c-1)a^2$$

Now, you can take square root and see what do you get.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you say the statement is not true? Yes, c is a constant greater than 1.

Comment: Let $c=2$ and see what do you get.

Comment: I get b=a (negative a ignored because of a > 0 ).

Comment: do you see any horizontal tangent?

Comment: Oh.... I got it thanks!